# Is this grammar LL(1)

Tags: parsing, ll-grammar

I have been asked to convert:

```
S → Sa | bSb | bc
```

to LL(1) so far I have:

```
S → bY
Y → SbF | cF
F → aF | ε
```

Is this LL(1)? If not would this be LL(1):

```
S → bY
Y → bYbF | cF
F → aF | ε
```

if neither of these would somebody please give me the correct answer and why thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you done so far to check whether your grammar is LL(1)? Ultimately, that's probably more valuable than just getting a binary yes/no here.

Comment: Well it is for a past paper which had no answers available. I've derived some words from it and it seems ok and I'm pretty sure it is ll(1) I'm just unsure about the S in the Y variable and whether I would need to substitute it in or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
S → Sa | bSb | bc
```

1. Remove left recursion:

   ````
   F -> aF | EPSILON```
   ````
2. Now left factor:

   ````
   F -> aF | EPSILON
   X -> SbF | cF```
   ````
3. Check the First and Follows:

   ````
   S: b
   X: b, c
   F: a, EPSILON```

   ```Follows():
   S: $, b
   X: $, b
   F: $, b```

   Everything checks out so it is LL(1) parsable.
   ````